# Sony, Camera how to discover camera over lan

Tags: camera, sony

I am using android studio and can run the sample code.
I have my camera connected to my local wifi which has a direct connection over the modem to my pc.
I know the IP of my camera.
How can I access my camera through my modem over a lan connection to my wifi modem.
Thanks,
-Scott

Answer (score 0):

For SSDP device discovery,  both camera and device have to be connected to the same subnet.
To access Camera Remote API beta, when you are using a Playmemories Camera Apps compatible camera (e.g. A6000, RX100M3) then [Smart Remote Control](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-F00002) application has to be started in the camera.

Best Regards, Prem, Developer World team